# Wrapping C++ class to use in Python

Tags: python, c++, boost, wrapper, cython

I have a device which can be controlled through a C++ class (https://github.com/stanleyseow/RF24/tree/master/RPi/RF24).

I'd like to be able to use this class in Python, and thought I could wrap it.

I found many ways to do it, but not much detailed documentation with examples. In particular, I found Boost, Cython, SWIG and the native C Python API.

Which one is the best method in which case ? And do you have some links to detailed documentations / examples about this ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no "best"; it depends entirely on your circumstances.

For a single class, the native C Python API isn't too difficult,
but you do have to create an entire module, then the class.  It
would be simpler if you exposed a procedural interface, rather
than a class.  If you only have one instance of the device, this
would be an appropriate solution.

SWIG is very good for taking C++ class definitions and
generating a Python module which contains them.  The resulting
code is relatively complex, since SWIG tries to cover all
possible versions of Python; for anything 2.7 or later (and
perhaps a little earlier), you can do everything directly in
C++, without any intermediate Python.

Boost makes extensive use of templates.  This isn't really an
appropriate solution for the problem; it adds a lot of
complexity for something that is relatively simple if done with
external tools, rather than metaprogramming.  Still, if the
underlying complexity doesn't scare you, it might not be that
hard to use.

I'm not familiar with Cython.

Globally, if all you have is one instance of one simple class,
using the native C API is probably no more difficult than the
other solutions, and introduces a minimum of added internal
complexity.

Comment: For now, I only need one instance of this class. But if it's not much more complex to be able to handle multiple instances of a class, I think it may be worth it.

Comment: Sorry, I messed up with last comment… : For now, I only need one instance of this class. But if it's not much more complex to be able to handle multiple instances of a class, I think it may be worth it. I need my generated Python code to be Python 3.3+ compatible. I'll have a look at SWIG and standard C API.

Comment: It's a little more complex: you have to create the module and its functions first, then add the class to it.  Defining a class isn't complex, but it is verbose: there's an enormous struct you have to fill out, for example.